# Wordpress image upload processing failing when images exceed certain dimensions

Tags: php, wordpress, image-processing

Hope you can help!

I have a Wordpress site hosted with 1and1.com, and since upgrading to Wordpress 3.7.1 I have been experiencing errors with the uploaded media - specifically images.

When large images are uploaded and inserted in the post, they are given `width='1'` and `height='1'` values, which I have diagnosed to be an error caused by a failure of the media upload/crunching in the first place.

By testing uploads of varying filesizes and dimensions, I have discovered the errors occur when an image is over approximately 2.2 megapixels (tested successfully at 1700x1275, failure at 1800x1350) regardless of filesize. When an image is too large, the image uploads successfully in its original form, but the processing of thumbnails, medium and large versions fails and the Media Uploader returns "An error occurred in the upload. Please try again later."

After researching the problem, I have tested the following to no avail:

1) Disabling all plug-ins

2) Re-installing WordPress

3) Creating a php.ini file to increase memory-limit (tested `memory-limit = 64M`, `memory-limit = 128M`, `memory-limit = 256M` and `memory-limit = 1024M`). N.B. I also altered the maximum upload size in the php.ini file to test whether it was in the right directory, which it was.

I don't have access to Apache Error Logging as the hosting is on a shared server.

Also looking back through media/posts, it seems large images have been uploading incorrectly since the site was launched a few years ago, so the error is nothing to do with Wordpress 3.7.1. However, only in 3.7.1 are they displayed with `width='1'` and `height='1'` values, seemingly when it can't find medium, large or thumb versions?

If I can't find a way to get the image uploading/crunching to work, is there a workaround that could help with the `width='1'` and `height='1'` being outputted?